# How to add Prefix for the attribute while marshling

Tags: java, attributes, marshalling, castor

I like to add prefix for attribute while marshaling using castors.

I would like to get result as like below

```xml
<ThesaurusConcept dc:identifier="C268">
    <ScopeNote xml:lang="en">
        <LexicalValue>index heading is Atomic absorption spectroscopy</LexicalValue>
    </ScopeNote>            
</ThesaurusConcept>
```

but I am getting

```xml
<ThesaurusConcept identifier="C621">
<ScopeNote lang="en">
    <LexicalValue>index heading is Atomic absorption spectroscopy</LexicalValue>
    </ScopeNote>  
</ThesaurusConcept>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer for my question

we need to add the following in **mapping.xml** file

```
<mapping  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> 

<bind-xml name="dc:identifier" node="attribute" ></bind-xml>
```

and also we need to set namespace by using following code.

```
Marshaller  casreactmp = new Marshaller(handler);
            casreactmp.setNamespaceMapping("dc", "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");
```